# Cancelled recurring event instance not in events list with singleEvents & showDeleted True

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

I have been caching Google calendar event data locally in a local database using the python api for v3.

I have this ID cached locally 16...hk_20140530T010000Z. The event has been deleted by a user using Google Calendar on the web, and was not deleted by any scripting. The user reported the event was still appearing in her reports from our local cache.

I investigated, assuming there had been a problem at some point in time and the scripts had simply missed canceling this event (I use updatedMin so I thought maybe something could have theoretically been missed.) However, even when I ran a full query of all data for this calendar this instance of the recurrence was nowhere to be seen. There were plenty of others in the recurrence that appeared, but this instance did not exist in the results from Google, cancelled or otherwise.

I pull these IDs directly from the results from google when I save them in the database, and the fact it exists tells me it had to have existed at some point. The fact it is no longer listed has me puzzled, as it should be there with a status of canceled from my understanding.

Does anyone have any suggestion on why this may be the case? We have 200+ calendars I sync and deleting and re-importing on a regular basis would be a very time consuming process.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that the user has not synced for a long while and the event deletion can be no longer found? Would you mind verifying that you are handling 410 errors correctly? https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync

Comment: Interesting. When you say "deletion can no longer be found" does that mean Google lets deletions disappear completely after some amount of time since being deleted? I've always thought they would stay once they're deleted. If they don't, that explains a lot.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for your help. If you want to put that as an answer I'll accept it, as the deletions disappearing do seem to be what was at fault. At some point in history a sync didn't succeed on my end and by the time I realized this past week I assume the deletion had disappeared from google. Better checking if a sync succeeded on my end is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event deletions can disappear after a while. Make sure to correctly handle the 410 response code when using old sync tokens / modified since values (http://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync).